# Excel DNA registering COM libraries in HKLM

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, excel-dna

I have a question about Excel DNA. I have a .DNA file which, using ExcelDNAPack, creates a .XLL Excel Add-In. I have chosen for the DLLs to be packed into the XLL.

When we load the XLL (as an Add-In, not by running regsvr32), the DLLs are registered under HKLM. I thought the DLLs would be registered under HKCU so that multiple users could run our Excel app with entirely separate COM registrations (the app, ultimately, will run for many users on a Citrix box, so this is important).

Maybe there is a setting I can put in the .dna file which specifies where the COM components should be registered?

Thanks,

PW

Comment: Duplicate of this discussion on CodePlex: https://exceldna.codeplex.com/discussions/450596

Answer (score 2):

According to Govert the registration is based on the user's permissions. If there is admin access then it registers in HKLM, otherwise it goes to HKCU. There's a thread about it [HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/j1TR4x8rXc4).

Comment: Indeed. I'd be happy to change it if I could detect the case where a process is running with an elevated token ('As Administrator') in a UAC context.